# Gotest - cannot use []int literal (type []int) as type args in field value

Tags: go

I am trying to test a basic sum function with a table test. Here is the function:

```
func Sum(nums []int) int {
    sum := 0
    for _, n := range nums {
        sum += n
    }
    return sum
}
```

I do know that the error is with the table args, but I don't understand why Golang will not accept the tests. It would be great to have some clarity. See test below and error:

```
import (
    "testing"
)

func TestSum(t *testing.T) {

    type args struct {
        nums []int
    }
    tests := []struct {
        name string
        args args
        want int
    }{
        {"test", []int{3, 4}, 7},
        {"test", []int{3, 3}, 6},

    }
    for _, tt := range tests {
        t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            if got := Sum(tt.args.nums); got != tt.want {
                t.Errorf("Sum() = %v, want %v", got, tt.want)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

`cannot use []int literal (type []int) as type args in field value`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because the second field of your anonymous structure is `args`, not `[]nums`

You should initialize it as with an explicitly typed `args` value.

```
{"test", args{nums: []int{3, 4}}, 7},
```

Or, if you prefer the field-less struct literals:

```
{"test", args{[]int{3, 4}}, 7},
```

Comment: @zerkms No problem! If you have time, I have other edit suggestions that need review as well.